# How to do a 'notes' cell like in Apple's Contacts

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm having trouble finding this answer. I want to do a cell like in Apple's Contacts. It's the notes cell. Just to clarify, in Contacts, when you are in edit mode, and go to add field and tap notes, and start editing, it seems like it behaves like a text view whereas you can hit return and it'll go to a new line. The cell's no larger than what you use. And naturally you'll see everything in the view when you're finished.

Does anyone know how to do this or where to find the info?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an normal cell and in it has an [UITextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html) Class Reference.

When you type and you need an new line resize the height of the cell and the height of the textView. When you reach you max height just allow textView scrolling.
Good luck.

To catch the textView events 
[UITextViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html)