# How is the 'notes' field implemented in iOS Contacts App?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, contacts

I need to create something very similar to the **notes** field in iOS Contacts application.

Does anyone know how to create the auto-resizing effect. I presume that the cell contains a `UILabel` on the left and an editable `UITextView` on the right.

[image: notes field]

I am aware that this question has been already [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046636/how-to-do-a-notes-cell-like-in-apples-contacts) however the answer posted was not detailed enough and I cannot leave a comment to ask for more detail.

Any thoughts are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: What do you need to know beyond the information in [the answer to the other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046636/how-to-do-a-notes-cell-like-in-apples-contacts/6046841#6046841)?

Comment: How to increase the height of the textview and the cell (I know that I have to use the heightForRow delegate - but I don't know **when** to increase it. And how to make the tableview scroll up just above the keyboard to make the text always visible

Comment: You should revise the question to ask that, then.

Answer (score 1):

Start with [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046636/how-to-do-a-notes-cell-like-in-apples-contacts/6046841#6046841) to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046636/how-to-do-a-notes-cell-like-in-apples-contacts).

You'll set some object, possibly the table view's delegate, as the delegate of the text field in the cell. When the text view delegate gets a `– textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` message (or perhaps just `-textViewDidChange:`) it can calculate the required height of the text view and, if that's different from the current height, call the table's `-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` method. This will cause the table to reload the row, effectively changing the height.

Comment: Ok I'll post back when I have something. Thanks @Caleb